# No spacing between enumerated items with \usepackage{enumerate}

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I use this code now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I want to decrease the line spacing between a,b,c. Can someone help me do this?

And how do I remove the space BEFORE enumerate?

Answer (score 100):

Better to use the latest and powerful `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Some text here.
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex]
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Here you may have to adjust these parameters as per your needs:

1. `\topsep`: space between first item and preceding paragraph.
2. `\partopsep`: extra space added to `\topsep` when environment starts a new paragraph.
3. `\itemsep`: space between successive items.

In the above code the parameters are set locally. If you want, you can make them global with the help of `\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex}`. For details, refer the `enumitem` manual at [texdoc](http://www.texdoc.net).

You can suppress all of these spaces by using `nolistsep`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some text here.
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this same manipulations in the `enumerate` package instead of `enumitem`?

Answer (score 31):

Instead of using a package, you can also use the built-in features and define a new environment

```
\newenvironment{tight_enumerate}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

This will nicely squeeze the items close together. If you need them even closer, you can use negative numbers, but be careful not to cause overlapping text.

Comment: How can I use this approach to affect whole document?

Comment: If you replace all enumerates in the document with tight_enumerate it should work out. If you don't want to do that you can also use `\renewenvironment{enumerate}` instead to overwrite the original enumerate settings (for this document)

Comment: I think this is correct way of doing it. In my case, I only wanted to modify `enumerate` for only specific list not all.

Answer (score 17):

`enumitem` offers ready-made options for eliminating the space between items and paragraphs within the list (`noitemsep`) or all vertical spacing (`nosep`):

[image: Standard enumitem options for killing vertical spacing]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \paragraph{List without vertical spacing between items and paragraphs:}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{enumerate}
  Something after the list.

  \paragraph{List without vertical spacing:}
  \kant[3]
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{enumerate}
  Something after the list.
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that `nolistsep` is now considered deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `enumitem` package instead of `enumerate`

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

then it will support the same suntax as the `enumerate` package.

The `enumerate` package does not provide any extra configurations other than the label.

Comment: Ah that worked great. `enumitem` was breaking some of my previous `enumerate` commands.