# How to reduce space between items in enumerate?

Tags: itemize

My question refers to previous question already asked on forum.

[No spacing between enumerated items with \usepackage{enumerate}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119919/no-spacing-between-enumerated-items-with-usepackageenumerate)

I need reduce space between enumerated items. How can i do it?

```
  \begin{enumerate}[-]
     \item ABC
     \item DEF
     \item XYZ
  \end{enumerate}
```

Regards

Answer (score 5):

The answer, as in the other thread, is to use `enumitem` instead of `enumerate` package.

If you load it with the `shortlabels` option

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

you can keep the same syntax of `enumerate`.

Then you can issue, for example

```
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
```

if you want to eliminate the spacing between items or

```
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=1pt}
```

if you want to reduce it to `1pt`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[-]
     \item ABC
     \item DEF
     \item XYZ
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want the change to be locally, instead of declaring

```
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
```

you can insert `noitemsep` in the `enumerate` options, as in

```
\begin{enumerate}[-,noitemsep]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default value of the `\itemsep` length. For example, if you want no space at all

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{}
```

or if you want a "small skip"

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{\smallskipamount}
```

To be put inside the `enumerate` environment if you want the change to be local to it.

By the way, the link you pointed already gives an answer…