# How can I define a unique vertical spacing value for all parts of my document which has lists and paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, paragraphs

I am trying to write my CV in LaTeX and I am not using a specific package for CV. I am coding it myself.

My problem is:

1. The space after normal paragraphs and the space
   after the lists are not the same. (spaces which are shown with red arrows in picture.)
2. The vertical space between my lines in paragraphs and vertical space between list lines are not the same. (spaces which are shown with blue arrows in picture; but these should not be the same value to the vertical spacing of the previous spacing which are shown by red arrows.)

Also, the vertical spacing in all the document is not the same and in some parts these spaces change. How can I have a unique vertical spacing in my whole document?

*Note: I do not know why a draft background appears in the MWE. So I am sorry for unwanted inconvenience.*

[image]

```
%pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt,after=\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{darkcandyapplered}{rgb}{0.64, 0.0, 0.0}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\betweenrules}

\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}% space at left
  {0ex}% space above
  {2ex}% space below

\newcommand{\betweenrules}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{darkcandyapplered}\vrule width 2.35cm height 1.5ex \hspace{1em}}%
  \color{darkcandyapplered}%
  #1% the title
  \hspace{1em}%
  \leaders\hrule height 1.5ex\hfill
}

\begin{document}
\section{Current Positions}
I have the following positions;\\
I am looking for some professional opportunities.
%
\section{Research Projects}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}
\item Research number 1.
\item Research number 2.
\end{enumerate}
% 
\section{References}
\noindent Available upon request.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like the main issue comes from the spacing in your `enumerate` environment – the skips in there can be redefined. Also, you can look up grid typesetting for solutions that will help you force LaTeX to use lines of an exactly equal height. This is not by default and can be quite tricky to do thoroughly, but a CV should be fairly simple.

Comment: The first part is regular text, make it a list as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the spacing after the `enumerate` environment using

```
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt,after=\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

You need, `\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}` instead. Also, it is better to use `enumitem` macros for defining label like

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
```

If you need the the redefintion of label globally, then add `label={[\arabic*]}` to `\setlist` after `nosep`.

```
%pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{darkcandyapplered}{rgb}{0.64, 0.0, 0.0}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\betweenrules}

\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}% space at left
  {0ex}% space above
  {2ex}% space below

\newcommand{\betweenrules}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{darkcandyapplered}\vrule width 2.35cm height 1.5ex \hspace{1em}}%
  \color{darkcandyapplered}%
  #1% the title
  \hspace{1em}%
  \leaders\hrule height 1.5ex\hfill
}

\begin{document}
\section{Current Positions}
I have the following positions;

I am looking for some professional opportunities.
%
\section{Research Projects}
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
\item Research number 1.
\item Research number 2.
\end{enumerate}
%
\section{References}
\noindent Available upon request.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used `itemsep=5pt` instead of `nosep` to add a little space between items to let them be more readable. Also thank you for your other answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119935/52417