# How do I decrease spacing (in LyX) between enumerate items

Tags: lyx, lists, enumerate

I'd like to do this without changing the spacing between normal paragraphs, just for numbered list items and their nested kin.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the `enumitem` module, write

```
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
```

in `Document settings -> Preamble` (I hope the translations are correct, because I have the Italian version).

For more infos or alternative solutions, see here: [No spacing between enumerated items with \usepackage{enumerate}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119919/no-spacing-between-enumerated-items-with-usepackageenumerate)

This is an example, save it as `something.lyx`, open it in LyX, and compile:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Enumerate
bar
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
foo
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

and this is the result:

[image]