# Cursive letter and spaces between lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing, enumitem, letters, letterspacing

I am using cursive letter with lined page.
However, the lined style appear only the first page.
My questions are:

1. how can I insert lined rules on all pages?
2. When I insert enumerate environment, the letters modify the spacing. How can I fix this?

Below, my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2.7cm,top=1.6cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{10ex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[eulergreek,noplusnominus,noequal,nohbar,nolessnomore,noasterisk]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\foreach \i in{2.1,2.2,...,28}
\foreach \x in{2,3,...,28}
\draw[line width=1pt,violet!40!white]([shift={(-1,\x)}]current page.south west)--([shift={(0,\x)}]current page.south east);
\foreach \t in{4,5,...,25}
\draw[line width=1pt,red!80!black]([shift={(1.8,-1)}]current page.south west)--([shift={(1.8,1)}]current page.north west);
   \end{tikzpicture}

 \baselineskip=1cm \vglue -3mm 
 
 \color{blue}
 \textbf{ Nome: Rafael Moreira }  \\
 
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{enumerate}
\item $f(8.4)$ se $f(8.1)=16.94410$, $f(8.3)=17.56492$, $f(8.6)=18.50515$, $f(8.7)=18.82091$.
\item $f(0.25)$ se $f(0.1) = 0.62049958$, $f(0.2) = -0.28398668$, $f(0.3) = 0.00660095$, $f(0.4) =
0.24842440$
\end{enumerate} 

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `atbegshi` you can put the `tikzpicture` as background in every page.

With `enumitem` it is possible adjust the parameter of a list. See the details in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119935/161015

[image: x2]

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.7cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=1cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{10ex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[eulergreek,noplusnominus,noequal,nohbar,nolessnomore,noasterisk]{mathastext}

\usepackage{atbegshi} % added
\usepackage{enumitem}  % added
    
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
        %\foreach \i in{2.1,2.2,...,28}  % not needed
        \foreach \x in{2,3,...,28}
        \draw[line width=1pt,violet!40!white]([shift={(-1,\x)}]current page.south west)--([shift={(0,\x)}]current page.south east);
        \foreach \t in{4,5,...,25}
        \draw[line width=1pt,red!80!black]([shift={(1.8,-1)}]current page.south west)--([shift={(1.8,1)}]current page.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}   
            }}
        
\setlength{\topmargin}{-81pt}  % needed to set right every page 
\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{\baselineskip}
    
 %  \baselineskip=1cm \vglue -3mm  
\color{blue}

\textbf{ Nome: Rafael Moreira }  \\

\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=-1ex,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex]
\item $f(8.4)$ se $f(8.1)=16.94410$, $f(8.3)=17.56492$, $f(8.6)=18.50515$, $f(8.7)=18.82091$.
\item $f(0.25)$ se $f(0.1) = 0.62049958$, $f(0.2) = -0.28398668$, $f(0.3) = 0.00660095$, $f(0.4) =
0.24842440$
\end{enumerate}     

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```